# The code gives segmentation error, how?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

```
#include`<stdio.h>`
#include`<stdlib.h>`
int main()
{
    int k, i, j,tot=0, htot=0, vtot=0, dtot=0, m, n;        
    int a[8][8] = {
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
};

for(i=0;i<8;i++)        
{ 
    htot=0;
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        htot += a[i][j];
        printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);    
    }    
    tot += htot ;
 }

if(tot == 8)
printf("Moving on to Vertical checking");
else
printf("Horizontal criterion not fulfilled %d ", tot);
tot=0;
for(j=0;j<8;j++)
{   
    vtot=0;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        vtot += a[i][j];
        printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
    }
    tot +=vtot;
}   
if(tot == 8) 
printf("Moving on to Diagonal checking");
else
printf("Vertical criterion not fulfilled %d ", tot);    

for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
    if(a[i][j])
    {
        m=i;
        n=j;
        while(n!=0)// running the loop leftwards
        {
        m++;
        n--;
        dtot +=a[m][n];     
        }
        printf("diagonal left total = %d", dtot);
        if(dtot == 1)
        {
        m=i;
        n=j;            
        while(n!=0)// running the loop rightwards
        {
        m++;
        n++;
        dtot +=a[m][n];
        }
        printf("diagonal right total = %d", dtot);
    }
} 
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The best thing to do is to run this through a debugger like gdb and tell us the exact line that the segmentation fault occurs on.

Comment: Where does it segfault? What does your debugger tell you? What is this even supposed to do?

Comment: Please indent your code so it can actually be read.

Comment: it's pretty obvious it will crash, print the values of `m` and `n`.

Comment: add `printf("a[%d][%d] is %d\n", m, n, a[m][n]);` right before the two statements `dtot += a[m][n];` to find out why your program segfaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(n!=0)// running the loop rightwards
{
  m++;
  n++;
  dtot +=a[m][n];
}
```

That seems a pretty obvious crash to me. Increasing `n` and checking for `n!=0`.

The loop previous to this probably also crashes because `m` runs out of array index.

Put some `printf`s for `m` and `n` in those loops. Even better: think about the array index ranges before you write your code.

Comment: Yeah, I found my error on this thing. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal runs aren't correctly bounded. You're only checking the n index, and you're checking it the wrong direction on the rightwards span. At some point n goes out of range and does an illegal array access.